# The discount must be removed with a certain method of payment for the goods Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, discount

Online store on Wordpress + Woocommerce.  We plan to add a discount on all products on our website. But it is necessary that when choosing a certain payment method "'wc_tinkoff_kvk", the discount is removed on the product. Discounts on different products - 5, 10, 20, 30%. Therefore, the method with the addition of a certain percentage is not suitable as I understand it.

The discount on the product is set using the promotional price "_sale_price".

Answer (score 0):

How do you set up discounts? Is a coupon applied to the cart or something different?

On the front end if you are using ajax you can do this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'myfunc_1052', 10, 1);

function myfunc_1052($cart) {
        if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && is_admin()  ) {
            return;
        }

        if(!is_checkout()) {
            return;
        }

        if ( WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' ) == 'wc_tinkoff_kvk' ) {

        //your logic here

        }


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wrote the assignment incorrectly. The discount on the product is set using the promotional price "_sale_price". Attached a screenshot

https://yadi.sk/d/RciyNYC2agrWZg